# Creating a SQL Server database for the first time at run time

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, vb.net-2010

I want to create a SQL Server database at runtime in my vb.net project. I know how to actually code the database but I am wondering where should I actually put the code? Should I be putting the code in the start up form or should it go into a class on it's own? Also, this project will be going on more than one pc at a particular site, so I only want the database to be created the first time the project is activated and then just be able query the database on different pcs after that. How do I do this? All help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Ok, so I should have been clearer on this. The project is going to be on 2 different pcs, it is for visitors entering a business. The pcs will be in reception and security. I need both pcs to access the same database with the same details in it. I don't want to have two different databases where details have to be put in twice. For example, if I enter at reception today and then go through security tomorrow, then all I should have to enter in security is why I'm entering the business again, I shouldn't have to put my details in a second time. How do I go about this? As I already said, I know how to code the database, but I want to know how to do what I stated in my question.

Thanks in advance for all help given.

Comment: Why don't you distribute an already made MDF file? Remember however that SQL Server should be installed on one machine on the target site. So it is not only a matter to create a database via code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the code in module or in form load then it will execute all the time when the form loads. it is wasting of time to check **whether the database exist or  not** in each run. So it is better to place a button with text **"Create database"** for this purpose(or menu item). it's click event will load the database. the following code can be used to create the **database dynamically on button click**

```vb
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'creating and initializing the connection string
        Dim myConnectionString As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
        'since we need to create a new database set the Initial Catalog as Master
        'Which means we are creating database under master DB
        Dim myCommand As String //to store the sql command to be executed
        myCommand = "CREATE database my_db" //the command that creates new database
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(myCommand, myConnectionString) // creating command for execution
        Try
            cmd.Connection.Open() //open a connection with cmd
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() //Execute the query
            cmd.Connection.Close() //Close the connection
        Catch
            MsgBox(" Already installed database", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, " MaS InfoTech- Warning")
        End Try
        'Creating table to the dynamicaly created database
        Try
            Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=my_db;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
          'here the connection string is initialized with Initial Catalog as my_db
            Dim sql As String //sql query string
            sql = "CREATE TABLE customer(cus_name varchar(50) NULL,address varchar(50) NULL,mobno numeric(18, 0) NULL,tin varchar(50) NULL,kg varchar(50) NULL)"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, cn) // create command with connection and query string 
            cmd.Connection.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Connection.Close()
          Catch
           MsgBox(" Already existing table", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, " MaS InfoTech- Warning")
          End Try
    End Sub
```